# How to use fn:starts-with() and fn:ends-with() with cts:uris()

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

My Requirement is, I want to return document URI only if path range index value is starts-with or ends-with some word.

As Per MarkLogic documentation I can only use ">, <, <=, >=, =, !=" to compare path range index value but in my requirement I want to use fn:starts-with() or fn:ends-with().

Is there any way to satisfy this requirement?

Comment: why don't you use `cts:uri-match("*/some/path*")` ?

Comment: Thanks, @bosari for your reply. If you look at my question, I want to use fn:starts-with() and fn:ends-with() on Path Range index values, not on URIs.

Comment: Did you look at `cts:value-match` yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`cts:value-match()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:value-match) with leading and trailing wildcards to find all of the values that start-with and end-with the value.

Then use [`cts:path-range-query()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:path-range-query) with those values in a call to [`cts:uris()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:uris)

```
let $path := "/doc/foo";
let $word := "bar";
(: find the values that start with and end with the $word :)
let $values-starts-and-ends-with := (
  cts:value-match(cts:path-reference($path), $word||"*"), 
  cts:value-match(cts:path-reference($path), "*"||$word)
) 
(: use those values to find the URIs of docs with those values at that path :)
cts:uris("", (), cts:path-range-query($path, "=", $values-starts-and-ends-with))
```